# How to hide vertical scrollbar in NavigationView?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm using `NavigationView`, when added many items in `NavigationView`, and set `PaneDisplayMode` to `LeftCompact`. It will automativally show the vertical scrollbar. I'm trying to hide it.

I looked up in `NavigationView`'s style in generic.xaml, and found all the items are in a `NavigationViewList`.

```
    <NavigationViewList x:Name="MenuItemsHost" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,0,0,20" 
SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" 
ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" 
ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" 
ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" 
SingleSelectionFollowsFocus="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=TemplateSettings.SingleSelectionFollowsFocus}" />
```

So I put `NavigationView`'s whole style into app.xaml, and add
`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Hidden` to `NavigationViewList`. Nothing changed.

I also found `NavigationViewList` is based on `ListView`, so I add `ListView`'s to app.xaml, and set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Hidden`. Neither works.

Why?

Comment: Have  you give a key to the `NavigationView`  style and use it with static resource reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to hide vertical scrollbar in NavigationView?

For my testing, it works within native `NavigationView` that add `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Hidden` into  `NavigationViewList`, but for 
[**microsoft-ui-xaml**](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) editing the style will cause the list missing, and it looks an issue. I will report it to the produce team, and you could also post the bug report in `microsoft-ui-xaml` github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) box.

Comment: OK, I have submit an issue to winui team, https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1862